# React-testing-library and <Link> Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I'm using `react-testing-library` to test a simple component which has a nested react-router-dom's `<Link>` inside of it and I am getting this error:

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by mocking the Link:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  Link: jest.fn().mockImplementation(({ children }) => {
    return children;
  }),
}));
```

That way I can test my component normally:

```
 test('render MyComponent with <Link>', async () => {
    const myListOfLinks = mockLinks();
    render(<MyComponent parents={myListOfLinks} />);
    const links = await screen.findByTestId('my-links');
    expect(MyComponent).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with `Link` component being `undefined`. In our case it was caused by existing jest mock. There was a file in our codebase under `__mocks__/react-router-dom.js` which didn't provide an implementation for `Link`. So all other tests were using mocked implmentation of `react-router-dom` module. Jest uses [convention](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) for automatic mocking of modules. Removing this mock solved the issue